# How to copy a photo from Camera Roll to app's Documents folder as a JPG/PNG?

Tags: iphone

How can I copy/move a photo from Camera Roll to an app's own Documents folder? `UIImagePickerController` returns a `UIImage *` by:

```
(UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]
```

How can I save the `UIImage *` as a file (best with all the EXIF information embedded)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using following code

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSArray *UsrDocPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *DocsDir = [UsrDocPath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [DocsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contents.png"];
    //Remove if necessary
    BOOL success = [FileManager fileExistsAtPath:path];
    if(success){
        [FileManager removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
    }
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```